# Access Picture in NodeJS public folder from Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I've searched around for an answer and couldn't find anyone else with this problem. I have an api in NodeJS using express and a website in Angular4. The back saves pictures in the public folder and saves its path in the database. The problem comes when I try to use those pictures in the website as an image source, because angular cannot find the public folder in its path.

The path would look like this: './public/artwork/1508457128377.png' in the database

I've tried putting an **alias** in the assets folder (which is the static folder for angular) and changing the path slightly but it doesn't work. Which is surprising since it does work when I copy/paste the actual public folder in as a test. In the code below, gallery is an array that contains the src paths for image tags.

```
  ngOnInit() {
this._fluxService.getHome().subscribe(activity => {
  console.log(activity)
  if (activity.length === 0) {
    this.gallery = null;
  } else {
    activity.map((item) => {
      if(this.gallery[0] === '') {
        this.gallery[0] = '/assets' + item.screenshot.substring(1);
      } else {
        this.gallery.push('/assets' + item.screenshot.substring(1));
      }
    });
  }
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  return false;
});
```

}

Is there a way that the front and back can share access to the same folder? The pictures in the public folder are generated from a chrome extension which directly speaks to the backend and cannot therefore be saved directly in the assets folder. At least, not that I know of.

Comment: No there is no way because angular cannot access local folders due to security reasons so instead of storing it local try uploading it to a cloud storage and use it in angular

Comment: Did you declare '/public' as static in express? Can you access [domain]/public/artwork/1508457128377.png in a browser? If not, you have static serving issues. Also, the '.' in ./public/artwork/1508457128377.png is going to cause problems with your URL path.